# Drupal behavior not working with Views ajax

Tags: views, ajax

I have a problem with applying my js to Views after its filter is changed using ajax. I'm really tearing my hairs out for a while...
As obvious in this question - my js is applied only on first load, after changing some filters and hitting send button the js is not working anymore. What is strange - if I uncomment last line with submit() the JS works! But - first time it reloads page with ajax, than after second change it reloads the page...

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.frontpage = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {


            var container = $(".category-select", context);
            var selector = $("#edit-field-category-tid", context);
            var submit = $("#edit-submit-frontpage", context);


            $(container.find("span"), context).click(function() {
            var tid = $(this).attr("data-taxonomy");
            var select = $(selector.find('option[value="'+tid+'"]'), context);
            if ( select.prop('selected') ) {
                $(this).removeClass("enabled");
                select.prop('selected',false);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("enabled");
                select.prop('selected',true);
            }
            //submit.click();
            });


        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I tried some other configurations and... It seems like that setting prop is not working correctly after ajax refresh. Seems strange to me, because ids are the same, it finds select (option) properly but it do not change its property.
Is it possible that it do the changes on old, i dont know - cached(?), site created before ajax refresh?

Comment: try "Drupal.attachBehaviors();" in the end of your function or in the pace of submit.click(); and try